# How can I filter this JSON data using ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

Given the following data:

```
products = [
  {
    id : "123",
    price : "10.5",
    quantity : 1,
    category1 : "Catagort-1",
    category2 : " ",
    category3 : " "

  },
  {
    id : "133",
    price : "10.5",
    quantity : 1,
    category1 : " ",
    category2 : " ",
    category3 : "Catagory-3"

  },
  {
    id : "144",
    price : "7.00",
    quantity : 1,
    category1 : "Catagort-1",
    category2 : " ",
    category3 : " "
  },
  {
    id : "155",
    price : "11.5",
    quantity : 1,
    category1 : "",
    category2 : "Catagory-2",
    category3 : ""
  },
  {
    id : "166",
    price : "9.00",
    quantity : 1,
    category1 : " ",
    category2 : " ",
    category3 : "Catagory-3"
  },
  {
    id : "177",
    price : "8.5",
    quantity : 1,
    category1 : "",
    category2 : "Catagory-2",
    category3 : ""
  }
];
```

I want to filter the above data like this:

- Given three arrays: `cat1[]`, `cat2[]` and `cat3[]`;
- Store all data that has a value for the `category1` attribute to the `cat1` array.

For example:

```
cat1= [
 {
        id : "123",
        price : "10.5",
        quantity : 1,
        category1 : "Catagort-1",
        category2 : " ",
        category3 : " "

      },
 {
        id : "144",
        price : "7.00",
        quantity : 1,
        category1 : "Catagort-1",
        category2 : " ",
        category3 : " "
      },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

```
this.products.forEach(res=>{
  if(res.category1=='Catagory-1'){
    this.cat1.push(res);
  }
  else if(res.category2 == 'Catagory-2'){
    this.cat2.push(res);
  }else if(res.category3 == 'Catagory-3'){
    this.cat3.push(res);
  }
})
```

**Method 2**

```
    this.cat1 = this.products.filter(res=>{
      return res.category1 == 'Catagory-1'
    });

    this.cat2 = this.products.filter(res=>{
      return res.category2 == 'Catagory-2'
    })

    this.cat3 = this.products.filter(res=>{
      return res.category3 == 'Catagory-3'
    });
```

Additionally, You can check out this library https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11
, this gives you a wide variety of functions to play with.